# How to setup parameters into jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a jenkins jobs that run autotests with parameters:

- HOST;
- EXPEIMENT;
- TAKE_NEW_SCREENSHOT;
- XML_NAME.

All of this parameters have default values, 
see screenshot before running parametrizing job:

[image: Parametrizing jenkins job before running]

I need to run several jobs simultaneously with only 2 parameters: HOST and EXPERIMENT. 
I created next pipeline-script:

```
def tasks = [:]

parameters {
    string(name: 'HOST', defaultValue: 'www', description: 'host: www, dev3, etc',)
    string(name: 'EXPERIMENT', defaultValue: 'withoutExperiment',)
}

tasks['Actions MyBox'] = {
    build job: 'MyDocs_Actions_And_Manage_Buttons_MyBox_Tests', parameters: [
        string(name: 'HOST', value: 'www'), 
        string(name: 'EXPERIMENT', value: 'withoutExperiment'), 
        booleanParam(name: 'TAKE_NEW_SCREENSHOT', value: false), 
        string(name: 'XML_NAME', value: 'my_docs_actions_buttons_mybox_tests')
    ]
}

tasks['DashBoard General'] = {
    build job: 'DashBoard_General_Tests', parameters: [
        string(name: 'HOST', value: 'www'), 
        string(name: 'EXPERIMENT', value: 'withoutExperiment'), 
        booleanParam(name: 'TAKE_NEW_SCREENSHOT', value: false), 
        string(name: 'XML_NAME', value: 'my_docs_dash_board_general_tests')
    ]
}

tasks['Actions InBox'] = {
    build job: 'MyDocs_Actions_Buttons_InBox_Tests', parameters: [
        string(name: 'HOST', value: 'www'), 
        string(name: 'EXPERIMENT', value: 'withoutExperiment'), 
        booleanParam(name: 'TAKE_NEW_SCREENSHOT', value: false), 
        string(name: 'XML_NAME', value: 'my_docs_actions_buttons_inbox_tests')
    ]
}

parallel tasks
```

and specified parameters in "General" pipeline configuration:

[image: pipeline configuration]

But when I run this pipeline item with parameter value != default value, for example specify HOST = dev12,

[image: pipepline item with not default value parameter]

anyway all jobs running simultaneously with default parameter values and build shows null specified parameter,

[image: null parameter HOST]

Help me please define a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing hardcoded values to your tasks. For example, you defined

```
tasks['Actions MyBox'] = {
    build job: 'MyDocs_Actions_And_Manage_Buttons_MyBox_Tests', parameters: [
        string(name: 'HOST', value: 'www'), 
        string(name: 'EXPERIMENT', value: 'withoutExperiment'), 
        booleanParam(name: 'TAKE_NEW_SCREENSHOT', value: false), 
        string(name: 'XML_NAME', value: 'my_docs_actions_buttons_mybox_tests')
    ]
}
```

In this case all parameters are hardcoded and each time when pipeline is executed the value of `HOST` will be `www`. And that's why you have `null` in the `HOST` parameter description in build execution info (because you're not specifying it in `build job` command).

So, you need to use something like `string(name:'HOST', value: "${params.HOST}")`